# Single query or stored procedure to fetch data

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have created three tables

Here I would like to fetch all question_tags and answers related to a perticular question(id).
for that needed Single query or stored procedure

```
create table questions(id varchar(100),title varchar(140),body varchar(2000),
primary key(id));

create table question_tags(id varchar(50),tag_name varchar(50),question_id varchar(100),
primary key(id),foreign key(question_id) references questions(id));


create table answers(id varchar(50),answer varchar(2000),question_id varchar(100),
primary key(id),foreign key(question_id) references questions(id));
```

and following data in table

```
     mysql> select * from questions;
     +----+-------+-------------+
     | id | title | body        |
     +----+-------+-------------+
     | 1  | a     | hello       |
     | 2  | b     | hii         |
     | 3  | c     | bye         |
     | 4  | d     | how are you |
     +----+-------+-------------+
     4 rows in set (0.03 sec)

     mysql> select * from question_tags
     +----+----------+-------------+
     | id | tag_name | question_id |
     +----+----------+-------------+
     | t1 | java     | 1           |
     | t2 | mysql    | 1           |
     | t3 | jquery   | 1           |
     +----+----------+-------------+
     3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

     mysql> select * from answers;
     +----+-----------+-------------+
     | id | answer    | question_id |
     +----+-----------+-------------+
     | a1 | good      | 1           |
     | a2 | excellent | 1           |
     | a3 | ok        | 1           |
     +----+-----------+-------------+
     3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So what is stopping you? What have you tried? Where is the question?

Comment: I dont know how to fetch multiple rows from different tables

Comment: Specifically, read about "outer joins".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you search for the JOIN [ON] Statement. For your Tablelayout it should be something like this:

```
SELECT `question_tags`.*, `answers`.* 
FROM `questions`
   JOIN  `answers` 
        ON `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id`
   JOIN `question_tags` 
        ON `questions`.`id` = `question_tags`.`question_id`
WHERE `questions`.`id` = {YOUR_ID}
```

Or only Question-Id, Answers, Tags:

```
SELECT `questions`.`id` AS `question_id`, 
         `question_tags`.`tag_name`, 
         `answers`.`answer` 
FROM `questions`
   JOIN  `answers` 
        ON `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id`
   JOIN `question_tags` 
        ON `questions`.`id` = `question_tags`.`question_id`
WHERE `questions`.`id` = 0
```

**EDIT:**
And for everything in one Row:

```
SELECT  `questions`.`id` AS  `question_id` ,
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `question_tags`.`tag_name` SEPARATOR ';') 
    FROM  `question_tags` 
    WHERE  `question_id` =0
) AS  `Tags` ,
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `answers`.`answer` SEPARATOR ';' ) 
    FROM  `answers` 
    WHERE  `question_id` =0
) AS  `Answers` 
FROM  `questions` 
WHERE  `questions`.`id` =0
```

Please keep in mind that this **isn't** the best way for doing this. I can't provide you a Stored Procedure since i'm unfamiliar with SP in MySQL.
In my Opinion there is no way to select/return/display your desired format as a Table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. how to do this with stored procedure so repeated data can be removed

Comment: THanks for your reply. This was me desired output

Answer (score -1):

The query is:

```
select * from questions join question_tags on (questions.id = question_tags.question_id) join answers on (questions.id=answers.question_id);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9606/2) is a fiddle; it greatly helps us assit you if you provide one with your question.
Please read about mySQL naming conventions (tables in signular) and about keyreferences (I have changed yours to `integer`s but you can also `auto_increment` etc).